# Android Phonegap Error: google is not defined

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application for iOS and Android which finds local ATMs. My Android version was running just fine until this week when it seems like Google changed some of the ways PhoneGap projects need to be built.

I now get an error which says:
**03-11 09:30:03.698: E/Web Console(8768): Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/map.js:36**

When I run this file on my Desktop browser everything works fine. For some reason this is no longer working on the phone.

I have tried using multiple different calls to the Google API including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
```

These worked perfectly last week on Android. These still work on iOS and my desktop Browser.

The specific line of code the error is pointing at is:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Which is the first call I make to the Google API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your script tags are working. Did you include the maps domain in your whitelist?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what happened but I must have removed that line accidentally! If you want to make an answer I can mark it correct.

Comment: You're welcome. Sure I'll do it - my shortest answer yet ;) Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you include the Google Maps domain in your whitelist ;)